# insert 3 columns into a table where only 2 columns are from another table

Tags: sql, insert, sqlite

I wish to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(col1, col2, col3 = 'constant literal')
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1;
```

So col1 and col2 are copied from table1 to table2, but col3 is set to be a constant value I want. The code above does not work. so how do i do this? I don't want set a default value to col3 by changing the schema.

I am using sqlite3 if relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, 'constant literal'
FROM table1
```